Самоисправляющийся HelloWorld("print")
В честь приближающегося 1 сентября предлагаю соревнование по написанию самоисправляющегося Hello world.
Сразу оговорюсь, что задание придумано на Python, но можно написать ответ на любом языке, где есть схожее с Python поведение:

в стандартную функцию вывода в консоль передается строка через указание последней внутри круглых скобок
ЯП позволяет запустить программу, заведомо написанную с ошибкой


Требуется написать код, в конце которого будет указана обратная команда HelloWorld (допустимо дописать обязательные для работы конструкции - например, end, скобки и т.п.):
# Любой Ваш код
HelloWorld("print")

После запуска в консоль выведется исправленный текст приложения Hello world:
print("HelloWorld")

При этом текст, который "отправляется на печать" (часть HelloWorld), можно менять - код должен аналогично работать и с такими командами:
hello_world("print")  >>>  print("hello_world")

test("print")         >>>  print("test")

Текст для вывода прописывается одним словом - как функция.
После него в скобках и кавычках указывается команда вывода - своя для ЯП.
Обеспечивать возможность изменения ("print") (или аналогичной в другом ЯП) не нужно.
Аналогично не обязательно обеспечивать работу приложения после вывода текста правильного кода HelloWorld.

Пример на JavaScript:
# Любой Ваш код
HelloWorld('console.log')

Пример на Pascal:
program Hello;
begin
  # Любой Ваш код
  HelloWorld('writeln')
end.


Критерии победы (по убыванию для случаев равенства голосов)

Самое большое количество голосов на момент подсчета
Наименьшее число символов кода (включается всё - и ваш код, и последняя строка с HelloWorld)
Наиболее ранний ответ

Подведение итогов - 1 сентября в 21:00 МСК
По итогам соревнования больше всего голосов получил ответ @CrazyElf - решение через перехват исключения NameError.
Но в ответах есть не менее интересные и неожиданные решения!
Спасибо всем за участие! Отдельное спасибо за решения на языках помимо Python!
Так самое короткое решение вышло у @extrn на Perl - 61 символ!

Изначальное моё решение задачи также придумано через перехват исключения NameError, только в размере вышло 111 символов:
import sys;sys.excepthook=lambda*a:print(f'''print("{str(a[1]).split()[1].strip("'")}")''')
HelloWorld("print")


getattr на глобал перегрузить и всё делов то. На паскале не получится

Одно из условий - возможность работы с любым текстом для вывода на печать, а не только HelloWorld. Как сделать такое через getattr лично у меня мыслей нет - если можно, то было бы интересно посмотреть

А я не пойму как без этого сделать. Хотя ...

ЯП позволяет запустить программу, заведомо написанную с синтаксической ошибкой В Python весь код проверяется на правильность синтаксиса и только потом запускается, поэтому запустить программу с синтаксической ошибкой ЯП вам не позволит, в приведённых примерах у нас не SyntaxError нужно превентить, а NameError :)

print("print") тоже нужно обрабатывать?

А награда будет!?

"Если скрипт после строчки: hello_world("print") не может продолжить выполнение дальнейших инструкций." или "код до строчки: hello_world("print") исключает её обработку" , то это противоречит заголовку вопроса: Самоисправляющийся Hello world , а значит — костыль.

Так: Аналогично не обязательно обеспечивать работу приложения после вывода текста правильного кода HelloWorld. не честно! Костыли с "Днём знаний" вообще ни как не увязываются... Вы, наверное, в дневнике оценки учителей подправляли (или вообще дневник теряли каждый месяц) ;)

Знание костылей - тоже знание :) И скорее не костылей, а неочевидных/нестандартных возможностей ЯП. Никто не будет в реальных задачах писать что-то подобное, но вот знания о механизмах ЯП из предложенных вариантов могут оказаться полезными

Внезапно... Я и не ожидал выиграть ))  Мне лично решения которые через чтение __file__ показались более правильными. И над ответом я не сильно работал. У некоторых (ну, вы знаете) и такой вариант, и сякой, и так, и эдак... Но вообще много интересных и неожиданных способов мы в Питоне узнали, так что конкурс оказался весьма полезным, спасибо! )

Mожно через перехват исключения NameError.
Но в интерактивном питоне это не работает (например, в Jupyter Notebook),
работает только при запуске из командной строки:
import traceback as tb
import sys
import re

def my_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    rx = re.compile(r'([^\(]+)\(\"([^\"]*)\"\)')
    line = next(iter(tb.extract_tb(traceback))).line
    text, command = rx.findall(line)[0]
    print(f'{command}("{text}")')

sys.excepthook = my_except_hook

hello_world("print")

Вывод:
print("hello_world")

Символов 320, оптимизировать по их количеству пока лениво.
И сам разбор пока не очень красивый.
Мне интересно было концепт попробовать.

UPD:
для конкурса, 182 символа:
import re,sys,traceback as t
def h(d,o,b):print('{1}("{0}")'.format(*re.findall(r'([^\(]+)\(\"([^\"]*)\"\)',next(iter(t.extract_tb(b))).line)[0]))
sys.excepthook=h
hello_world("print")


Обработать исключение это прикольно!

@AnnaBazueva Да, исключение конечно, почему я прерывание то написал ))

Позволила себе чуть-чуть исправить ответ. Сделала raw string чтоб в консоли не выскакивало предупреждение: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('   rx = re.compile('([^\(]+)\(\"([^\"]*)\"\)') .
Ну и немного отформатировала, для лучшей читаемости.

Да, и символы посчитала == 320, дальше оптимизировать уже в ущерб читаемости...

Давайте, подтягивайтесь! ;) Может предложите решение с модулем pdb!? Я пробовала, но пока не решила... Может не зря писали: почему я прерывание то написал )) –  CrazyElf 

@AnnaBazueva Да некогда мне - дела, работа ))  Мне тут, похоже, уже и минусов понаставили помимо плюсов, знать бы - за что )

Я сперва поставила +, но потом в комментах под вопросом предложила костыли не считать решением. Мне сказали надо быть последовательной, и я была вынуждена отозвать свой голос "За".

@AnnaBazueva Не, там именно прям минус чей-то, а не отозванный голос, судя по статистике )  Если она, конечно, не глючит

Ну, это не я... Мой против должен быть виден как отозванный.

Использование lambda вместо def h и h после равенства должно сэкономить один перевод строки.

Perl, 61 символ
Перечитал условие, и только сейчас обратил внимание, что одинарные кавычки допустимы
AUTOLOAD{$AUTOLOAD=~/::/;print"@_('$'')"}
HelloWorld('print')

Try it online!
В читабельном виде
use strict;
use warnings;

# функция, выполняемая при вызове неизвестного имени.
# sub в ее случае указывать необязательно
sub AUTOLOAD {
    # аргументы записываются в массив @_
    my @args = @_;
    # а в переменную $AUTOLOAD - полное имя функции, например "main::HelloWorld"
    our $AUTOLOAD;
    # с помощью регулярного выражения, ищем в ней ::
    $AUTOLOAD =~ /::/;
    # не попавшая под регулярное выражение часть строки записывается в переменную $'
    my $name = $';
    # при интерполяции, массив отображается в виде разделенной пробелами строки,
    # но аргумент у нас один, так что пробелы не появятся
    print("@args('$name')")
}

HelloWorld("print")


Python  145 - 164 символов (с последней строчкой и без)
Хотелось придумать что-то оригинальное :)
exec('#'+open(__file__).read(),type('',(dict,),{'__getitem__':lambda s,i:s.get(i,lambda x:print(f"{x}({i!r})"))})(__builtins__.__dict__));exit()
helloworld("print")

Более читабельная версия
class DefaultDict(dict):  # пользовательский класс в котором изменён дандер получения элемента
    def __getitem__(self, key):  # в случае если элемента нет в словаре возвращаем лямбду
        return self.get(key, lambda arg: print(f"{arg}({key!r})"))


# создаём новый экземпляр нашего класса передавая в него словарь всех built-in имен чтобы не сломать логику их получения
env_globals = DefaultDict(__builtins__.__dict__)
# читаем исходный код этого файла и обрезаем первые n строчек в которых лежит наш код чтобы недопустить рекурсии
source_code = "".join(open(__file__).readlines()[14:])

# запускаем весь оставшийся код передавая в качестве словаря глобальных переменных экземпляр нашего класса
exec(source_code, env_globals)
# выходим из программы чтобы не выполнять весь код ниже ещё раз и не получить NameError
exit()

helloworld("print")  # теперь эта и любая другая строчка ниже обработается как надо

Никаких костылей, честно, схавает даже такой код:
exec('#'+open(__file__).read(),type('',(dict,),{'__getitem__':lambda s,i:s.get(i,lambda x:print(f"{x}({i!r})"))})(__builtins__.__dict__));exit()

import turtle

helloworld("print")

turtle.tracer(-1)
turtle.pensize(40)
turtle.teleport(-50, -80)
turtle.dot(40)
turtle.teleport(-50, 80)
turtle.dot(40)

turtle.teleport(60, -186)
turtle.left(50)
for i in range(81):
    turtle.forward(5)
    turtle.left(1)

print(":)")

Ohh_HelloWorld("print")

turtle.mainloop()

А ещё, в отличии от других решений на Python, мой код ловит любые вызовы функций в рантайме, так что такой код тоже сработает:
exec('#'+open(__file__).read(),type('',(dict,),{'__getitem__':lambda s,i:s.get(i,lambda x:print(f"{x}({i!r})"))})(__builtins__.__dict__));exit()

computed_str = "hello_" + "world"

globals()[computed_str]("print")


А этому решению поставила "+"...

Python, 85 символов
_,s=open(__file__);a,b,_=s.split('"');print(f'{b}("{a}\b")')and\
HelloWorld("print")

Этот же код в более читабельном виде:
_, s = open(__file__); a, b, _ = s.split('"'); print(f'{b}("{a}\b")') and \
HelloWorld("print")

print в конце первой строки возвращает None. \ там же склеивает первую и вторую строки. Выражение None and ... никогда не вычисляет второй аргумент. Последняя строка файла не вычисляется и к ошибке не приводит.
Программа читает собственный код, предполагая что в нём ровно две строки (_, s = open(__file__)), разбирает вторую строку (a, b, _ = s.split('"')), печатает нужный результат. Переменная a содержит лишнюю открывающую скобку, её удаляет символ \b при печати. Итог выглядит правильно, но если перенаправить его в поток, можно увидеть и отрывающую скобку и backspace, который её удаляет:

$ python temp.py
print("HelloWorld")

$ python temp.py | python -c "print(repr(input()))"
'print("HelloWorld(\x08")'


Если "print" всегда один и тот же, то 83 символа:
_,s=open(__file__);a,_=s.split('(');print(f'print("{a}")')and\
HelloWorld("print")


Прикольный костыль!

Обходной приём (на техническом жаргоне — «костыль») — относительно быстрое и простое решение проблемы, применяемое для срочного устранения её последствий, но не влияющее на причины её возникновения. — аргумент ! ?

Подкрепляю цитатой из этого ответа: Выражение None and ... никогда не вычисляет второй аргумент.

Python, 120 символов
import inspect as i;*_,f=i.currentframe().f_code.co_names;locals()[f]=lambda s:print(f'{s}("{f}")')
HelloWorld("print")

В читабельном виде:
import inspect

fname = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_names[-1]

locals()[fname] = lambda s: print(f'{s}("{fname}")')

HelloWorld("print")

inspect.currentframe().f_code извлекает код, который интерпретатор Питона исполняет прямо сейчас. .co_names - список всех идентификаторов упомянутых в текущем коде. Имена в списке перечислены по порядку первого появления. Нам нужно последнее имя.
В следующей строке этому имени присваивается функция печати.
Когда интепретатор доходит до последней строки, функция в ней уже определена и печатает, то что нужно.
P.S. Решение обходится без чтения файла исходного кода с диска.

Этому решению поставила "+", но с натяжкой. Обработка последнего имени это подгонка под условия задачи (по определению - костыль). Если решение докрутить, символов будет немного больше.

Я ведь поставила "+" этому ответу... Если Вы добавите к решению несколько символов ради "Дня знаний" – это не уменьшит ценность Вашего ответа (использование модуля inspect). Подумайте...

@AnnaBazueva, мы с вами по разному смотрим на задачу. Я следую правилам, перечисленным в вопросе, вы добавляете к ним свои. На каждого не угодишь, мой ответ такой какой он есть. Если вы считаете, что можно сделать лучше, сделайте, добавьте ещё один ответ. Зрители рассудят. Спасибо за плюсик!

Станислав, развлекаясь не забывайте об основной цели ruSO: "Наша цель — собрать лучшие ответы на все вопросы, поэтому, если вам попадутся сообщения, требующие улучшения, вы можете отредактировать их.". Ваш ответ почти этому соответствует. Попробуйте посмотреть глазами того, кто будет читать спустя время...

Во всех подсчётах:

перевод строки считается за 1 символ, но только если он обязателен (несогласные могут удалить или заменить на ; по необходимости)
console.log в браузерных версиях перед подсчётом надо заменить на alert

Во всех решениях предполагается, что команда вывода в файле одна (хотя некоторые могут быть улучшены для нескольких) и она будет единственным кодом в файле помимо обёртки.
HTML + JS, 128 символов
Ограничения на выводимый текст: запрещены все ключевые слова и несколько глобальных свойств.


eval(document.currentScript.textContent.replace(/.*?(\w+)\("(.*)"\).*/s,"$1=()=>$2('$1')"))
HelloWorld("console.log")



Минимальный рабочий (невалидный) html-файл с заменой console.log на print будет выглядеть так:
<script>eval(document.currentScript.textContent.replace(/.*?(\w+)\("(.*)"\).*/s,"$1=()=>$2('$1')"))
HelloWorld("alert")</script>

NodeJS, 104 символа
Ограничения на выводимый текст: запрещены все ключевые слова и несколько глобальных свойств (например, undefined).
eval((""+arguments.callee).replace(/.*?(\w+)\("(.*)"\).*/s,"$1=()=>$2('$1')"))
HelloWorld("console.log")

NodeJS, 111 символов
Ограничения на выводимый текст: запрещены все ключевые слова.
console.log((""+arguments.callee).replace(/.*?(\w+)\("(.*)"\).*/s,"$2('$1')"))
return
HelloWorld("console.log")


Поставил плюсы авансом, но перечитайте условие: размер helloworld("print") учитывается, выводить нужно в виде print("helloworld"), а не просто helloworld

@extrn, блин.. Невнимательно читал, завтра исправлю.

@extrn, все ответы обновлены.

Браузерный JS, 93-6*3 = 75 символов
Ограничения на выводимый текст: запрещены не все ключевые слова.
На выведенную ошибку обращать внимания не надо - это сниппет так работает. Если смотреть в консоли браузера, то ошибки там нет.
После вывода исполнение скрипта прекратится.
Аргумент (имя функции для вывода) игнорируется (вроде по условию так можно?).


onerror=e=>!console.log('console.log("'+e.match(/: (\w+)/)[1]+'")')
HelloWorld("console.log")



PS: console.log -> alert при подсчёте.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, все ответы обновлены.

Можно в самом начале прочитать исполняемый файл, вывести все исправленные принты и завершить процесс чтобы не наткнуться на NameError ошибку.
Итого получилось 105 символов моего кода + строчка hello world
_,*f=open(__file__);[l[:-1]and(j:=l.strip().split("("),print(j[1][1:-2]+f"('{j[0]}')"))for l in f];exit()

helloworld("print")

Код просто свайпает название функции и аргумент в любой непустой строчке, так что например type_age("input") точно так же переведется в input("type_age")
Если же мы уверены что будем работать только с принтами то это можно захардкодить и получить 86 символов
_,*f=open(__file__);[l[:-1]and(print(f"print('{l.split("(")[0]}')"))for l in f];exit()

helloworld("print")

Скорее всего можно оптимизировать и еще но лучше всё таки понимать более четкие критерии задачи

И за этот костыль я голосовала против.

@AnnaBazueva если с другой стороны посмотреть то это самый первый ответ который мог чем-то вдохновить других! Не так уж и плохо что он костылём является

Нет, конечно, "Костыли" – это не плохо! Но только вне конкурса, согласны!? А автор вопроса ещё не ответил на мой комментарий и не уточнил другие моменты...

@AnnaBazueva, ну и зря. Ради костылей вопрос и задавали.

@Qwertiy Очевидно, что повестка на ruSO формируется "кодерами", их менталитет в сочетании с обрывочными знаниями — идеальный субстрат для "КОСТЫЛЕЙ".
Но это не означает, что не надо пытаться корректировать повестку. А в Вашем случае, поддержка этой повестки — преступление.

@AnnaBazueva, ну, ты можешь иметь такую позицию, но именно из-за таких людей я практически не отвечаю на английском SO - мне неинтересно что-то делать на подобном сайте.

@Qwertiy Вы ведь понимаете, что мне прививают такую позицию!? И даже знаете кто (в том числе и помогая с формулировкой моих сообщений). Всем, даже очень опытным "кодерам" нужна не менее опытная "Señorita". Я подрасту, окрепну (профессионально) и работать под моим началом будет большая удача!

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Решение (не костыль) 136 символов!
Код для конкурса:
import re
for f in re.findall(r'\w+(?=\(\"pr)',open(__file__).read()):locals()[f]=lambda x,f=f:print(f'{x}("{f}")')
Hello_world("print")

Этот код не допускает исключения NameError !
Читаемый вариант:
import re

def create_function(name):
    def func(param):
        print(f'{param}("{name}")')
    return func

for f in re.findall(r'\w+(?=\(\"print\"\))', open(__file__).read()):
    locals()[f] = create_function(f)

Hello_world("print")
It_is_not_print("print")

output:
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK> & c:/KWORK/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/KWORK/not_print.py
print("Hello_world")
print("It_is_not_print")
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK> 


locals()[f]=lambda x,f=f:print(f'{x}("{f}")') серьезно подсократит код :) но вопрос, является ли print единственным возможным аргументом, все еще актуален

@extrn Спасибо, за подсказку! Чуть позже обновлю код для конкурса (подожду уточнений по заданию, и ещё не ясно будет ли награда...).

locals()[f]=lambda s:print(f'{s}("{f}")').

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, так ещё короче (потом переделаю), спасибо! А Вы случайно не сможете предложить решение с модулем pdb ! ?

Я знаю как сделать через dis.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Это тоже глубоко под капотом... Давайте, неважно сколько будет символов! ;) (К дню знаний ведь конкурс!)

Попробуйте сами: dis.dis(i.currentframe().f_code). Там всё будет видно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy короче, но перестанет работать с несколькими разными вызовами, как в примере, хоть для задачи это и не требуется.

@extrn короче, но перестанет работать с несколькими разными вызовами, как в примере - это про dis?

@AnnaBazueva нет, про лябмду без параметра по умолчанию. переменная f будет переписываться при каждой итерации. Но, опять же, это не важно. вызов этой функции будет в коде всего один. Наверное, можно еще с exec(f'def {f}...: поэкспериментировать

@extrn Ясно. А что на счёт pdb? можно из кода обрабатывать pdb.set_trace() ? (столкнулась с конфликтом при использовании sys.stdout  или  sys.settrace())

@AnnaBazueva приведите что ли пример того, как вы хотите использовать pdb, я пока не вижу в нем особой пользы для этой задачи.

@extrn Посмотрите мой связанный вопрос, пожалуйста!

Javascript, 92 символа (для браузера 86)
Ограничения на выводимый текст: запрещены все ключевые слова и больше ничего.
Перевод строки необязателен, в браузере можно alert.


with(new Proxy({},{has:t=>1,get:(t,s)=>f=>eval(f)(f+'("'+s+'")')}))
HelloWorld("console.log")



PS: Кажется, самое чистое решение из моих js'ных.

Python (156 символов)
Вот моё решение. С re:
import re

g = re.search(r'(\w+)\("(\w+)"\)', open(__file__).read().splitlines()[-1]).groups()
print(g[1] + '("' + g[0] + '")')

exit()

HelloWorld("print")


Perl, 63 байт
$_=<DATA>;/\("/;print"print$&$`\")"
__END__
HelloWorld("print")


Хорошее решение. мой первый вариант тоже был через <DATA>, но я отказался от него, т.к. ENDHelloWorld("print") это просто кусок текста в хитрых кавычках, а не команда/функция языка.

Полностью согласен, Вам тоже лайк. Я предложил только альтернативное решение для выполнения данного условия задачи. Ваша функция еще и работает, и она уже была предложена.

AUTOLOAD в perl как раз и предназначен для таких вещей, но уже был пример, а без него тоже можно вполне обойтись с помощью typeglob, только код будет длиннее и имена надо указывать. Пример:
for my$z(qw(HelloWorld)){*{$z}=sub{print"@_("$z")"}};
HelloWorld("print")

Костыль на 147 символов!
import sys,contextlib as c
@c.contextmanager
def e():
 try:yield
 except:print(f'print("{sys.exc_info()[1].name}")')
with e():\
Hello_world("print")

Используется контекстный менеджер.
output:
print("Hello_world")

Читабельный код:
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def try_except():
    try:
        yield
    except NameError:
        print(f'print("{sys.exc_info()[1].name}")')
        
with try_except():
    Hello_world("print")


Этот костыль, побочный продукт попыток использовать модуль pdb.

Четыре пробела отступа можно заменить на один пробел, или на одну табуляцию.

@StanislavVolodarskiy ОК, еще минус 6 символов... Спасибо!

Костыль на 156 символов!
import sys,traceback as t
def h(о,o,k):print('{1}("{0}")'.format(*next(iter(t.extract_tb(k))).line[:-2].split('("')))
sys.excepthook=h
hello_world("print")

Это решение @CrazyElf, только без модуля re.

Вот пример кода на ассемблере x86 MASM, который решает поставленную задачу:
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
    outputString db "print(""HelloWorld"")", 0 ; Исправленная строка для вывода

.code
start:
    ; Получаем хендл стандартного вывода (консоли)
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE

    ; Выводим строку в консоль
    mov ecx, outputString
    invoke lstrlen, ecx
    invoke WriteConsole, eax, addr outputString, eax, NULL, NULL

    ; Завершение программы
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

HelloWorld MACRO cmd
    outputString db cmd, '("HelloWorld")', 0
ENDM

    HelloWorld("print")  ; Последняя строка кода

end start

Объяснение:

outputString: Строка, которая будет выведена в консоль. В данном примере она формируется макросом HelloWorld.
start: Основная точка входа в программу, где сначала получаем хендл стандартного вывода (консоли) с помощью GetStdHandle, затем выводим строку outputString в консоль с помощью WriteConsole.
HelloWorld MACRO: Этот макрос принимает команду (например, "print") и формирует строку в формате cmd("HelloWorld").
Invoke WriteConsole: Функция WriteConsole используется для вывода строки в консоль. Она требует указания хендла консоли, строки для вывода, её длины и других параметров.
Invoke ExitProcess: Завершение программы.

Как это работает:

Макрос HelloWorld генерирует строку, которая представляет собой команду для вывода текста, например, print("HelloWorld").
Эта строка затем выводится в консоль через стандартный вывод с помощью функций Windows API.

Этот код полностью соответствует требованиям задачи и выводит исправленный текст (например, print("HelloWorld")) непосредственно в консоль.
Ограничения

Этот код работает только на Windows и только на архитектуре x86. Для другой ос или другой архитектуры нужен совсем другой код
Этот код работает только с Hello world, допустим с test("print") это работать не будет. Правда вы можете добавить макрос test, чтоб это заработало.
В этом коде слишком много символов, поэтому его автор не претендует на звания победителя конкурса.

Примечание
Ответ не стоит рассматривать, как серъёзное решение.

Но ведь выведенная строка не является программой для вывода строки на ассемблере?

@Qwertiy, но ведь я получил то, что требовалось. Или вы хотите, чтоб я вывел 30 строк? Да и на Python, если Hello world("test") сделать выводится test("Hello world") и вы будете говорить, что это не программа вывода на Python?

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    cod=f.read()
with open('lib.py', 'w') as f:
    cod=f.write('''
def helloworld(a:str) -> str:
    print(f'{a}("helloworld")')
''')
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'from lib import helloworld\n{cod}')


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Что-то по-моему это фигня какая-то...
